# rake db:schema:load could not find a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, activeadmin

**EDIT** from [normalocity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249543/normalocity): My answer hasn't been able to solve this problem, so I'm posting a bounty for alternate solutions.

---

**Original question:**

I started to work on a Rails project a week ago, changing many times the database schema using migrations. Yesterday I try to create my database (developement environnement, default configuration) from scratch using these commands :

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:schema:load
```

I got this message when loading the schema using --trace option :

```
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'galleries'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:439:in `table_structure'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:322:in `columns'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `block in initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `yield'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `default'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `block in initialize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `yield'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `default'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `columns_hash'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:145:in `locking_enabled?'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:110:in `to_a'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `all'
/home/fabien/Dropbox/portfolio/app/admin/photos.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:13:in `instance_eval'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/dsl.rb:13:in `run_registration_block'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:171:in `parse_registration_block'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:50:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:87:in `register'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin.rb:60:in `register'
/home/fabien/Dropbox/portfolio/app/admin/photos.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:132:in `block in load!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:132:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:132:in `load!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/application.rb:155:in `routes'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin.rb:63:in `routes'
/home/fabien/Dropbox/portfolio/config/routes.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:258:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:258:in `eval_block'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:235:in `draw'
/home/fabien/Dropbox/portfolio/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `block in load_paths'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `load_paths'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `reload!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:87:in `reload_routes!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:28:in `block in initialize'
/    var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeadmin-0.3.4/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:45:in `block in attach!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:404:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:46:in `prepare!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/fabien/Dropbox/portfolio/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:193:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
```

As Rails beginner, I have no idea how to solve this issue especially my schema.rb have commands to create th galleries table.

My code is available here: https://github.com/fabienengels/portfolio

Comment: The top-most line in your code that it's dying on is `/home/fabien/Dropbox/portfolio/app/admin/photos.rb:10:in 'block in <top (required)>'` where you reference `Gallery.all.each` - did you make any recent changes to that file/line? Check your `git log`. Also, after `db:drop` did you just try `db:migrate` instead of `db:schema:load` to see if there is a difference? It might fail on a specific migration, and maybe that would help track down the problem.

Comment: Commenting out app/admin/photos.rb :

Gallery.all.each do |gallery|
  scope gallery.slug.to_sym do |photos|
    photos.where(:gallery_id => gallery)
  end
end

It works ... how can I fix this without commenting these lines each times I want to create the db ? 

(thank you for the clue ! :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your `/app/admin/photos.rb`

```
# /app/admin/photos.rb
index :as => :grid, :columns => 6 do |photo|
    Gallery.all.each do |gallery|
      scope gallery.slug.to_sym do |photos|
        photos.where(:gallery_id => gallery)
      end
    end
    # link_to(image_tag(photo.file.url(:thumb)), admin_photo_path(photo))
end
```

you need to put that code inside the `index` block. I commented out your link tag there. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to design your grid/block/whatever. just make sure it's in the index scope. Good luck.

Comment: It works ... so obvious, so simple, I fell stupid :) Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2):

So the issue is that when your app loads, it's loading up your activeadmin stuff. That in turn ends up running `Gallery.all` to know what scopes to setup.

Running a rake task like `schema:load` still loads the app, so it's still trying to do `Gallery.all` but you've just dropped/recreated the db so it's quite rightly saying that the table isn't there.

What you'd like to be able to do is tell ActiveAdmin not to bother configuring itself, as you're just running some migrations.

Luckily, there is a global variable `$rails_rake_task` that is set in those cases. I'd try not running the code in your active_admin initialiser whenever `$rails_rake_task` is true or if that doesn't work also not doing any activeadmin configuration (e.g. the stuff in app/admin/photos) if `$rails_rake_task` is true.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ActiveAdmin before, but from the documentation, but it seems like you can only reference a single model within an `ActiveAdmin.register` block, or that you simply haven't made the `Gallery` model visible inside of this file.

So, in `app/admin/photos.rb` where you have

```
ActiveAdmin.register Photo do
  ...

  Gallery.all.each do |gallery|              # <= this is invalid, because this file 
    scope gallery.slug.to_sym do |photos|    # doesn't know what `Gallery` (and therefore
      photos.where(:gallery_id => gallery)   # `galleries` table`) is referring to
    end
  end

  ....
end
```

I'm not sure how to do nested `ActiveAdmin` registrations, or even if you can, but the error message you're getting is telling you that `Gallery` is not accessible within the scope of this file, and therefore, it's like, "What 'galleries table? We have no 'galleries' table here.".

So, you could try one of these two things to resolve it and see what happens - hopefully this is either the answer, or will lead you to the answer:

- At the very top of the `app/admin/photos.rb` file, add this exact line:

  - `require '../models/gallery'`
- If that doesn't work, then instead of `Gallery.all.each...` try

  - `ActiveAdmin.register Gallery do` followed by that same block

Comment: I added the require line but now I get this error :

fabien@mrtea:~/Dropbox/portfolio$ rake db:schema:load
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ../models/gallery

I dont't think your second solution will work with ActiveAdmin, it'll show the links in the wrong section of the administration interface.

Comment: Ok, I just have the path wrong. Basically what you want to do is `require '/path/to/app/models/gallery.rb'`. The failure is just telling you that the path I gave you isn't right. If correcting the path doesn't work, however, then I'm not sure how to fix it, and will withdraw my answer.

Comment: I tried with : require 'app/models/gallery.rb'
I got :

fabien@mrtea:~/Dropbox/portfolio$ rake db:schema:load
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- app/models/gallery.rb

Trying : require 'gallery.rb' doesn't work neither (I got the initial error :/ )

Comment: Try just `require 'gallery`` or `require 'app/models/gallery'`

Comment: neither work ... :(

I also trier this : https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Creating-dynamic-scopes

But I still get the same error ...

Comment: Hm, then I'm afraid I'm not sure what's wrong. I posted a 150 rep bounty to try to get it answered.

Comment: I opened a ticket on the github project, hope I'll get an answer.

Thank you for your help